# Rails 6 + yarn + datatables issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatables, yarnpkg, webpacker, ruby-on-rails-6

I bumped into troubles with webpacker. I'm using Rails 6.beta3 and trying to add Datatables to my app. My steps:

```
 yarn add datatables.net-dt
```

then in `app/javascript/packs/application.js`:

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap';
import 'popper.js/dist/popper.js';

require( 'datatables.net-dt' )();
```

`config/webpack/environment.js`:

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const webpack = require('webpack')
module.exports = environment
environment.plugins.append('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery',
  Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
}))
```

After this if load a page I get an error in js console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '$' of undefined
    at DataTable (jquery.dataTables.js:129)
```

`jquery.dataTables.js`:

```
 var DataTable = function DataTable(options) {
    this.$ = function (sSelector, oOpts) { // <---------error is here. Turns out this is not defined variable
      return this.api(true).$(sSelector, oOpts); 
    };
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: I have this exact same error and cannot figure it out. I have no problems that I can see in my application.js. Other files load fine...it is just the datatables that is having the problem. On the same line as yours.

Comment: Look at my `application.js` example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opps. Its my bad. I found the issue. At the end of `app/javascript/packs/application.js` there was an error. I thought it didn't make impact on overall performance, but after eliminating of this things started working properly.

Answer (score 1):

my `app.js`

```
// that code so it'll be compiled.

require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap';
require('select2');
import 'popper.js/dist/popper.js';
require("chart.js");
require("leaflet");


import $ from 'jquery';
window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;
// var dt = require( 'datatables.net-dt' );

// var dt = require( 'datatables.net-bs4' )( window, window.$ );

require('datatables.net-bs4');
var moment = require('moment');
window.moment = moment
require('bootstrap-daterangepicker');

var feather = require('feather-icons/dist/feather.js')


function onready() {
  feather.replace()
  console.log('onready')
}

$(document).on('ready turbolinks:load', onready);

/* globals Chart:false, feather:false */



(function () {  
  feather.replace()

}())
```

Comment: Thanks. My problem was that I had `require('datatables.net-bs4')();` (like you have in the original post). That seems to not work. I needed `require('datatables.net-bs4');` (no trailing () )

Answer (score 0):

My `app/javascript/packs/application.js`

```js
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap';
import 'popper.js/dist/popper.js';
```

Answer (score 0):

My application.js

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap';
import 'popper.js/dist/popper.js';
require( 'datatables.net-dt' )();
```

And the result is

```
jquery.dataTables.js:129 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '$' of undefined
    at DataTable (jquery.dataTables.js:129)
    at Module../app/javascript/packs/application.js (application.js:38)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at bootstrap:83
    at bootstrap:83
```

The odd thing is the bootstrap part of the stack!

Comment: For those of you finding this via google, I needed to remove the trail `()` from the datatables call, so that it says `require( 'datatables.net-dt' );`